# Oracle SP giving PLS-00201 ORA-06550 error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have created a SP as below:
The purpose is the pass 2 params to xyz.
The SP xyz will read records from a table t1 and store in a cursor.
xyz in turn will call another SP sp2 in a loop with the records stored in the cursor.
When I tried to run this in TOAD, I got the error

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'abc.xyz' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE abc.xyz(year IN number, ver IN number)
IS 
  cursor my_cur  (year IN number, ver IN number) IS
    select p1, p2, p3, 
           p4, p5, p6 
      from abc.t1 
     where p2=year  
       and p3=ver;   

  my_row  my_cur%rowtype;
  params varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
    for IN my_cur(year, ver) loop
        params := '' || my_row.p1      || ''  ||',' 
                     || my_row.p2 || ',' 
                     || my_row.p3     || ',' 
                     || my_row.p4 || ',' 
                     || my_row.p5 || ',' 
                     || '' || my_row.p6 || ''

         dbms_output.put_line(params); 

         exec sp2(params);
         params := '';
    end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Do you mean to create a procedure with a name with a dot in it? Or do you really want to create a package with a procedure in it?

Comment: @Colin'tHart, I am find with the SP, I would like to know how to add a single quote around my_row.p1 in the params. Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is compiling

exec within a PLSQL block is not valid syntax. exec is a shortcut for sqlplus begin p; end;

```
 1  create or replace PROCEDURE xyz(year IN number, ver IN number)
  2  IS
  3    cursor my_cur  (year IN number, ver IN number) IS
  4  select p1, p2, p3,
  5     p4, p5, p6
  6    from t1
  7   where p2=year
  8     and p3=ver;
  9    --my_row  my_cur%rowtype;
 10    params varchar2(1000);
 11  BEGIN
 12  for  my_row IN my_cur(year, ver) loop
 13      params := '' || my_row.p1      || ''  ||','
 14           || my_row.p2 || ','
 15           || my_row.p3     || ','
 16           || my_row.p4 || ','
 17           || my_row.p5 || ','
 18           || '' || my_row.p6 || '';
 19       dbms_output.put_line(params);
 20       sp2(params);
 21       params := '';
 22  end loop;
 23* END;

Procedure created.
```

Comment: I would like add a single quote around my_row.p1 in the params. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: || ''' || my_row.p1 || ''' ||

Comment: thanks @Bjarte Brant. Is there any exception handling that we can do here. Just in case if there are some null values some where to skip that row seemlessly and continue with the next row.

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically telling you there is no VALID (compiled) procedure by that name or you called with incorrect type/number of parameters!

Did your code compile? It had 2 errors and i post here with the corrections.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc.xyz (year IN NUMBER, ver IN NUMBER)
IS
   CURSOR my_cur (year IN NUMBER, ver IN NUMBER)
   IS
      SELECT p1,
             p2,
             p3,
             p4,
             p5,
             p6
        FROM abc.t1
       WHERE p2 = year AND p3 = ver;

   my_row   my_cur%ROWTYPE;
   params   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   FOR my_row IN my_cur (year, ver)
   LOOP
      params :=
            ''
         || my_row.p1
         || ''
         || ','
         || my_row.p2
         || ','
         || my_row.p3
         || ','
         || my_row.p4
         || ','
         || my_row.p5
         || ','
         || ''
         || my_row.p6
         || '';

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (params);

       sp2(params);
      params := '';
   END LOOP;
END;
```